# How to get documents in Google firestore by created\updated date.?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

i want to get only the documents that are newly created and\or updated in my collections\sub collections.
i see we have a create_date , update_date metadata methods on the document object (using python SDK).

can we use it and how.? or is there any better ways i can do it easier.

Regards,
Sai

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to query Firestore by this metadata. If you need to use such timestamps in your queries, you'll need to add them to your documents as regular fields, typically setting them as [server-side timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) (to prevent clients from tampering with them).

Also see: [How can I query firestore by document snapshot updateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502660/how-can-i-query-firestore-by-document-snapshot-updatetime/54504341#54504341), which I'll mark your question as a duplicate of now that I found it.