# Using firestore meta createTime and updateTime

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've realized that there is private meta information "createTime" and "updateTime" in every Firestore document.

```
{
 ...

  "_createTime": {
    "_seconds": 1657794552,
    "_nanoseconds": 15469000
  },
  "_updateTime": {
    "_seconds": 1657794552,
    "_nanoseconds": 200837000
  }
}
```

Simply, Is there any reason I have to use my own "createdAt" and "updatedAt" fields?
May I use these already existing "_updateTime,_createTime" values in my app logic?

Comment: Why not use them, since they already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can query by metadata,you can only access it. As mentioned in this [stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504341/18265638), There is no way to query on the metadata that Firestore automatically maintains. If you need to query then you will need to add a field with that value to the document's data.

Firebase Firestore provides create_time and update_time timestamps  in v1, if you only need output.Have a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#document)

**create_time**

- Output only. The time at which the document was created.
- This value increases monotonically when a document is deleted then recreated. It can also be compared to values from other documents and the read_time of a query.

**update_time**

- Output only. The time at which the document was last changed.
- This value is initially set to the create_time then increases monotonically with each change to the document. It can also be compared to values from other documents and the read_time of a query.

Comment: OK, this is enough answer! If I have little intention to read the data by date, I need to make my own createdAt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2023, `create_time` and `update_time` are no longer available on `doc`. You can access `doc.createTime` and `doc.updateTime`, which are of Firestore Timestamp type.

From `firestore.d.ts`. Also see [this Firestore doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/test/test.firestore.DocumentSnapshotOptions).

```
  /**
   * A `QueryDocumentSnapshot` contains data read from a document in your
   * Firestore database as part of a query. The document is guaranteed to exist
   * and its data can be extracted with `.data()` or `.get(<field>)` to get a
   * specific field.
   *
   * A `QueryDocumentSnapshot` offers the same API surface as a
   * `DocumentSnapshot`. Since query results contain only existing documents, the
   * `exists` property will always be true and `data()` will never return
   * 'undefined'.
   */
  export class QueryDocumentSnapshot<
    T = DocumentData
  > extends DocumentSnapshot<T> {
    private constructor();

    /**
     * The time the document was created.
     */
    readonly createTime: Timestamp;

    /**
     * The time the document was last updated (at the time the snapshot was
     * generated).
     */
    readonly updateTime: Timestamp;

    /**
     * Retrieves all fields in the document as an Object.
     *
     * @override
     * @return An Object containing all fields in the document.
     */
    data(): T;
  }
```